# Is it OK to delete the old AI answer Help Center article, now that there's a new one in place?

Tags: discussion, help-center, ai-generated-content

We're currently [experimenting with a banner on the answer box](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) that cautions users against posting AI-generated answers. As part of this release, we deployed a [new Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) about AI-authored answers that's linked under 'Learn more' within the banner:

> [image: Screenshot of the AI answer reminder box that appears on answer form.]

This new article notionally supplants [the previous Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), but the previous article was not removed when the AI-generated content warning launched.

The question here is a quick double check before deletion — is there any reason to keep the old article around? Are we gonna lose anything of value by deleting it?

---

Edit: Deleted.

Comment: If we are getting (have got) a new article, can the suggestion(s) here be considered too please? [Extend AI content policy to articles and other content that is meant to be used as part of the knowledgebase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426908/extend-ai-content-policy-to-articles-and-other-content-that-is-meant-to-be-used) At the moment the article exclusively references answers still.

Comment: Dunno how much time I have for addon work at the moment @ThomA, so I don't want to overpromise. I like that post, though. With a little refinement (or if folks think it's ready to go), flag a mod to slap [status-review] on it, and if they think it's good to go as well, it'll enter the CM workflow.

Comment: Thanks @Slate . The fact that your response is positive is a good sign. I've stuck a flag on the post for a mod to make the change. many thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I'd say yes, it's redundant.

---

My original thought on this was no, because I believed the original covered more than just answering, but that's not the case; one could certainly take bits and pieces of it and make the claim that the article is banning gpt generated content across the entire site, but neither the original or the new one does that. Both are clearly only talking about posting answers.

Should similar help center articles exist for posting questions/articles/discussions? The [inauthentic-usage policy](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) already covers this and is linked in the new article so maybe only the one for answers is needed given it's where this is most abused?

Comment: Are they actually? Meta questions asking about ChatGPT in questions  as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421960/what-should-i-do-about-chatgpt-content-in-questions-not-answers were closed as duplicates of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421988/what-should-i-do-if-i-suspect-that-a-question-or-answer-is-written-by-chatgpt which does not make any distinction.

Comment: Also this one about questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425285/is-it-ok-to-answer-the-stack-overflow-questions-using-chatgpt-ai-own-logic just duped by this one about answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424968/is-re-worded-chatgpt-answer-allowed

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Well as of July or so [the GPT ban post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) says "__*All* use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow__" (emphasis not mine). I think the only question is whether the old and new help center content makes the same point differently clear or not.

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of avoiding link rot / death (there are plenty of comments out there and posts linking to that page), I think it'd be nice to let `/help/gpt-policy` continue to *exist*- but just not show it in the Help Center navigation, and put a highly visible notice at the top that points to the new page. If the policy becomes outdated in the future, that notice would/should be updated to say that as well. Yeah, I know web-archives are a thing (I've archived that page probably several times), but for the sake of people who received such comments on their posts and haven't come back yet to read them, It'd be nice to not expect them to know they can find it in a web archive.

Comment: Sadly, we don't have this functionality at the moment, so far as I am aware.

Comment: Or have it redirect to the new policy

Comment: @Mithical that works too. I initially disregarded that solution since according to Catija, the old one's content was "problematic", but reading exactly what she said again more carefully, the main problem she raised is that it's focused on the company instead of the community (not sure what the other problems are)

Comment: @Slate If it's just Markdown, a big header (one `#` symbol) could be used to point to the new page, and a normal markdown link could go to the Wayback Machine. Or, a one cell table could be (ab)used with some Unicode alert symbols to fake a warning dialog. Hardly _perfect_, but it might be _good enough_

Comment: In the ~20-30 hours since the policy page was deleted, 20 people have seen the 404 page there. One is me, a good number are probably y'all since this is still on Hot Meta Posts. Someone got there before the /help cache refreshed. Not a high rate of hits. All but a couple hits to /help/gpt-policy came from Meta Stack Overflow - links that could be updated here.